# What does 011111100 refer to in this LC-3 Code?

Tags: assembly, binary, lc3, machine-code

Okay so I am looking at an example program in LC-3 and one line of code is as follows:

```
0010 0 10 011111100 ; R2 <- M[x3100]
```

So I understand that the code is taking the contents at address x3100 and storing them into R2, however I am confused as to how they acquired the offset part of the binary code. When I look up 01111110 in binary, it's 252 with hex number being FC. So how does this relate to the x3100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate, referred to as the `PCOffset9` in some texts, is a pc-relative offset.  Thus, the more complete program is probably something like this:

```
      .ORIG x3000
3000  ...
3001  ...
3002  ...
3003  LD R2, #252
      ...
      ...
3100

      .END
```

When this instruction executes, the PC holds the value x3003, which is used to fetch the instruction `LD R2, #252` from memory.  During that instruction's execution, first the PC is used to fetch the instruction, then it is incremented, and next, the "effective address" is computed as `ea = PC + PCOffset9`.  Here PC is x3004 (was x3003 then +1), and the immediate is xFC, so their sum is x3100.  That same offset #252 will refer to a different memory location, if used in another instruction (i.e. at a location other than x3003).  Note that the `PCOffset9` is a 9-bit field that is signed: before the above addition to the PC, it is sign extended to 16-bits.  Being signed it can reach forwards & backwards, so the range is -256 to +255.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation! I guess my problem was that I didn't realize adding and subtracting Hex numbers is not like regular integers

Comment: Though the computer does storage of numbers and addition using binary, and we often use hex to represent binary, I think of addition and subtraction as working the same regardless of the number base.  In some sense, registers just hold numbers without a number base: number bases are for sharing numbers in string form (sequence of characters), e.g. I/O, printing, input, etc..  If you have a question on that, ask.  Here, x3004 + xFC = #12292 + #252 =  #12544 = x3100.